# Issue while logging CLI

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and was trying to login to CLI using SNOWSQL and below is the message that I get after entering my credentials.

```
C:\Users\some_username>snowsql -a zw43405.us-east-2
User: some_username
Password:
123456 (n/a): Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://zw43405.us-east-2.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=8bca193a-712d-4832-b8cc-ea0bb5d327cc&request_guid=f540096e-3988-4b82-b7cc-dd3585ebf602
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error means the URL was not resolved. US-East-2 is in Ohio, correct?  For the account piece, try this syntax instead at the start of your command with the ".aws" added on the end:

```
snowsql -a <account>.us-east-2.aws
```

You can see example syntax [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-log-in.html#step-1-log-into-snowsql) for each region in the docs. Also, I recommend **not** sharing your account name, username, or password in the forums.